# Display last 3 articles in 3 columns layout in Homepage

Tags: 7, nodes

I would like to erase the welcome message on my homepage and to do that I need to add the last 3 articles created which will be stored in 3 columns like : [**article1**][**article2**][**article3**]

Any ideas to do that? Maybe with Display suite or Mini Panels something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) with a descending sort on create date and limit the number of displayed items to 3. For the layout you can define css for the .views-row class (ex. width: 33%), for the styling you can use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or use views fields display mode.